# Bug with Compile and Log2?

Tags: warning-messages, compile

It seems that `Log2` in `Compile` gives numerical errors (`CompiledFunction::cfn`) if the input is not a power of 2.

For instance:

```
test1 = Compile[{{in, _Integer}}, Log2[in]];
test1[3]
```

gives an error and proceeds with an uncompiled evaluation.

However:

```
test2 = Compile[{{in, _Integer}}, Log[2, in]];
test2[3]
```

works correctly.

Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: `Log10[]` is also affected.

Comment: Just for noting it: `Log2[N[in]]` works.

Comment: `Log2[N[in]]` adds a integer to real conversion.

Comment: `Compile[{{in, _Real}}, Log2[in]]` works.

Comment: `test2` does two integer to real conversions. One for `2` and one for the argument `in`.

Comment: If you look at `CompilePrint@test1` and `CompilePrint@test2`, I think one can infer that `Log2[integer]` is intentionally a special-case integer function.  (Apparently undocumented?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the internal structure of the compiled functions, we can see a distinct call to an integer-valued function `Log2` of an integer argument.  There is also one for a real-valued function `Log2` of a real argument. The first example I think shows that the integer `Log2` is intentional. There are similar special integer functions for `Log10`, `Power`, `Gamma` and perhaps others.  It is easy to imagine reasons why one would want to do integer calculations with such functions.  As far as I know, these special cases are not documented.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];

test1 = Compile[{{in, _Integer}}, Log2[in]];
CompilePrint@test1

(*
        1 argument
        2 Integer registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        Result = I1

1   I1 = Log2[ I0]
2   Return
*)

test3 = Compile[{{re, _Real}}, Log2[re]];
CompilePrint@test3

(*
        1 argument
        2 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = R1

1   R1 = Log2[ R0]
2   Return
*)
```

The byte codes (from `List @@ test1`, `List @@ test3`) for the `Log2` instructions are respectively

```
{40, 36, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1}    (* I1 = Log2[ I0] *)
{40, 36, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1}    (* R1 = Log2[ R0] *)
```

The `40, 36` identifies `Log2`; the `2, 0, x` and `3, 0, x` specify the register types of the input and output, `_Integer` (`2`) and `_Real` (`3`), of rank `0` (scalar), and of register numbers `0`, `1` resp.

I tried constructing a `CompiledFunction` with the "instruction"

```
{40, 36, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}    (* R0 = Log2[ I0] *)
```

but it crashed the kernel. (I tried doing it by hand imitating the output of `List @@ test1` and other compiled functions.)  I concluded that such a function is not implemented.

Comment: Nice analysis, very insightful!

Comment: @sebhofer Thanks! -- Side note: "Type conversion" can be accomplished with `Compile[{{in, _Integer}}, Log2[N[in]]]`.  (There is no call to `N` per se; it just converts to `Real` via `R0 = I0` and then calls `Log2[ R0]`.  If `in` is type `_Real` to begin with, then `N` is ignored.)